# How to Make pom.xml Relative when deployed in AWS EC2?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pom.xml

I would like to deploy my app in AWS EC2. How to make the pom.xml file, containing the following, relative? Thanks.

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <directory>/Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard/target</directory>
        ...
</build>
```

Comment: add more information, this doesn't actually help

Comment: what kind of info do you need? It's a J2EE application, using Maven.
I want to make /Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard relative, so when it's deployed in EC2, it will automatically refer to the directory in EC2. /Users/admin/Developers/workspace/my-media-dashboard is the directory in my local machine.
Or does anyone has example, on how you write the pom.xml, to make the directory relative?